# 90s Prostitute reference in Law & Order: SVU

Tags: analysis, law-and-order-svu

Episode 4 in season 1 of *Law & Order: SVU* is about a policeman that kills prostitutes, and one night he killed a woman that was in good health and had good nutrition, and the mortician referred to her as a prostitute from the 90's. Why?

Comment: Possibly because it was the 90's?

Comment: Someone that commits sexual acts for money may be considered a prostitute. The health and nutrition of such a person is irrelevant. In fact, I've heard of prostitutes that make more money than I do by a large margin, and I'm at least upper middle class.

Comment: Could be **Manhattan streets numbered 90-99**, especially if he said "*East* 90s" or "*West* 90s". These are parts of the Upper East Side and Upper West Side areas (East and West of Central Park), which are as Wikipedia puts it "affluent" and "[primarily] residential".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> The M.E.: "Stomach contents include soybeans; vegetables; whole grains. A health conscious hooker."
>
> Olivia: "How 90's."

Saying that a *health conscious hooker is so 90's* in the 1990's would be like saying, "How millennial." in 2010. I'm not sure what it is now. The year isn't important; it's just a saying. Every decade has had its health kicks; coffee and eggs seem to have been continually debated throughout the last 100 years. Renewable energy? *How 70's.*

The 90's were a strange convergence of opportunity and availability, and could leave you with a feeling of *we can do anything* and *we can do better*. See *The Dot Com Bubble* to learn how that ended. AFAIK, the 90's were also **the first decade in America that the trend to become health conscious became trendy.**

So, *how 90's* of that hooker it was to be concerned with their food choices, while they subjected their bodies to prostitution.

In retrospect, I can't rule out the chance that Olivia might have meant something more along the lines of, "Kids these days...", but I still think the comment is more about *a sign of the times*.

Comment: Wow, Mezuraa, thank you!! I didnt know, very good analogy, so 80s was sex, drugs and rnr? :D